# Send data thru TCP port of an AWS EC2 instance using the Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, ip

I have a Telematics device from which I am trying to send some bytes of data to an AWS EC2 instance using the Elastic IP (as the device requires a static ip). When I install Wireshark in  the EC2 instance, I do not see the data coming thru although the device is not reporting any error.

Comment: Did you open the port in the security group associated with the instance?

Comment: I opened the port in the EC2 machine - Adminsitrative tools >> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security. Is this not enough?

Comment: Definitely not.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot. That answers and it fixed the same.